# Magento programmatically add product website not showing

Tags: magento

I wonder if anyone can help me with this. I've tried both methods below to programmatically add a product to a website (tick to a website an existing product, not create one) but neither made the product available on front-end. Back-end added fine.

Method 1

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(6318);
$product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
$product->setStatus(1);
$product->save();
```

Method 2

```
$websiteId = array(1);

$productId = array(6318);

$actionModel = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action');
$actionModel->updateWebsites($productId, $websiteId, 'add');
```

Tried with reindex as well but nothing.

```
$process = Mage::getModel('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_product_attribute');
$process->reindexAll();
```

I have done full cache clearing as well as full reindex from back-end but nothing.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!
Leo

Answer (score 1):

Follow some following steps in admin, edit product you created and check

```
1. Status of product ( must be enabled )
2. Stock Availability ( must be in stock )
3. Its qty
4. Websites ( if available must be checked )
5. Add product in some category and open that category on frontend.
```

If any value is missing or wrong then add/change that and check frontend.

Comment: Hi Ravi, it's all ok. For instance, if I simply open the product in the backend and just save it without changing anything, it then appears in the frontend. So something in the code not triggering that. Thanks Leo

Comment: Okay, which means you are missing some relation while creating product programatically and when you just save it again without changing anything from backend, magento relate missing table...
try one thing, create 2 products one from admin and another using script and see the difference.

Comment: @RaviMule How to find how many products enabled with a website? request to any DB query or script?